# why Automatic differentiation and gradient tape need to use context manager?

Tags: python, tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

Context managers can change two two related operations into one.For example:

```
with open('some_file', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Hola!')
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
file = open('some_file', 'w')
try:
    file.write('Hola!')
finally:
    file.close()
```

But in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function
I found:

```
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

what is it equivalent to?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a python expert but I think that with is defined by `__enter__` method and `__exit__` method (https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).
For tf.GradientTape method `__enter__` is :

```
  def __enter__(self):
    """Enters a context inside which operations are recorded on this tape."""
    self._push_tape()
    return self
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L801-L804

and for `__exit__` method

```
  def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
    """Exits the recording context, no further operations are traced."""
    if self._recording:
      self._pop_tape()
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L806-L809

then

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
```

is

```
tape = tf.GradientTape()
tape.push_tape()
loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
self._pop_tape()
```